# Difference between hint and cue

Tags: word-difference

Cue, as defined in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cue):

> Definition of cue
>
> 1
>
> **a** : a signal (such as a word, phrase, or bit of stage business) to a performer to begin a specific speech or action That last line is
>   your cue to exit the stage.
>
> **b** : something serving a comparable purpose : [HINT] I'll take that yawn as my cue to leave.

I feel CUE has the similar meaning as HINT in this case. Can we say:

- That last line is your **hint** to exit the stage.
- I'll take that yawn as my **hint** to leave.

I am not sure if these two words have some overlaps in meaning. Or sometimes they are interchangeable in some circumstances?

Comment: No, "**hint**" is just something aiding you in understanding, thus is similar to **give a clue**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have some overlap in meaning but they're not the same.

A hint is a thing used to help discover unknown or forgotten information. A cue is more about coordinating timing.  The common idiom "I'm waiting for my cue" means that I know what to do but am waiting for the signal to do it.

Don't confuse "cue" with "clue".

In your examples:

The actor knows that they need to leave the stage. The cue let's them know the right time.  It would only be a hint if the actor didn't know what to do.

The yawn is more of a hint because it carries the message that the person is sleepy and it is a good idea to leave.  It is a cue in the sense that the person is intending to leave and the yawn signals that now is the right time.

Comment: This is a very good explanation! I learnt it. Thanks!